# Is it possible to delete duplicate rows from a table without knowing it's columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to delete all the duplicate rows from an arbitrary table in a database when you don't know the table's structure (it's columns) using only plain SQL (without using PL/SQL)?

```sql
-- The code should look something like this
DELETE FROM tableName -- tableName can be changed
WHERE ...
```

So, as an example, for the following table:

```sql
.-------.
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | -- (1)
| 2 | 1 | -- (2)
| 2 | 1 | -- (3) duplicate of (2)
| 3 | 2 | -- (4)
| 3 | 2 | -- (5) duplicate of (4)
| 3 | 2 | -- (6) duplicate of (4)
'-------'
```

the result should be as follows:

```sql
.-------.
| A | B |
|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | -- (1)
| 2 | 1 | -- (2)
| 3 | 2 | -- (4)
'-------'
```

Comment: My previous solution was to delete all the rows and insert the rows from distinct select, but it might get quite slow.

Comment: Truncating a table and then inserting back into it will be faster than delete and insert if you are deleting more than 25% or so of the records -- although I am remembering the percentage from a stackoverflow post and haven't found a source at this time.

Comment: Why "without using PL/SQL"? The most natural solution uses dynamic SQL, which is really PL/SQL. You could do it all "in SQL" by writing a query against catalog views to generate the text of a SQL statement to delete the desired rows, but **why**? What's wrong with PL/SQL?

Comment: @mathguy Because this is what my instructor wants me to do at the University :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct * from TableA INTO TableB; 
truncate TableA;
insert into TableA select * from tableB;
drop tableB;
```

Additional answers from the comments:

Establish a CTE (construct this dynamically using parameterized SQL and information schema)

```
;WITH cteExample (val1, val2, RN) as 
( select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by val1, val2 order by val1, val2) as RN from tableA) 
-- select * from cteExample -- to verify results
delete from cteExample where RN > 1 -- to delete duplicate records
```

Utilize distinct if you know the tables will have a primary key (as they should)

```
;WITH cteExample as (select distinct * from TableA) delete a from cteExample b right join TableA a on b.primaryKey = a.PrimaryKey where b.PrimaryKey is null;
```

Lastly, skip the CTE entirely if you want:

```
delete a from TableA a left join (select distinct * from TableA) b on a.PK = b.PK 
where b.PK is null
```

All of these statements would be best served constructed dynamically using a stored procedure or the equivalent of exec sp_executeSQL (if avail) in order to grab the column names without knowledge of the columns ahead of time.

Comment: Well, I did the same thing previously, but it makes an auto-commit (because of the truncate) and might get quite slow when dealing with lots of rows while we might need to delete just a few of them.

Comment: Hi John, the only other way I know to do this is with a CTE. I'm more comfortable with SQL server than Oracle, but basically you would use a CTE and a partition by clause in order to identify distinct records by rownumber and delete all >1 (the duplicated rows) -- I can try to drum up a SQL Fiddle in Oracle for you if you aren't familiar with this type of thing?

Comment: @JohnBlumen . . . If you have a reasonable number of duplicates, this is probably the best approach.  `truncate` and `insert` is probably faster than a bunch of deletes.

Comment: @SeanBrookins I'm not familliar with CTE. Can you provide the simplest example possible (just the syntax, I will google the rest)?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I agree, although when the number of rows is huge but the number of duplicate rows is quite small, it is better to delete just these duplicates.

Comment: John, sure. `;WITH cteExample (val1, val2, RN) as ( select *, 
ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION by val1, val2 order by val1, val2) as RN
 from tableA) select * from cteExample` -- You would then use parameterized query against Oracle's information schema equivalent to create a list of column names with a string concatenation prior to constructing the CTE, which would then be able to run against any arbitrary data set.
Instead of the select statement, you would say `delete from cteExample where RN > 1` -- the select is so that you can view the results and adjust in your test case until satisfied

Comment: John - additionally you could use the CTE to establish a select distinct and then delete where the row doesn't exist on the main table assuming you have a primary key. Example: `;WITH cteExample as (select distinct * from TableA) delete a from cteExample b right join TableA a on b.primaryKey = a.PrimaryKey where b.PrimaryKey is null;`

Comment: If the OP will do what you suggest, without locking the original table (even assuming that the additional one is "private" in some way), in a multi-user environment, the result will be a huge mess if other users (or applications) modify data in the original table.